# Annoying while loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I'm a beginner in python programming and i have gotten to the topic "while loop"
I want to know why my code prints only the "Thank you" after
while name != "your name"
is changed to
While name == "your name"
Without iterating through the loop. Thanks. Below is the code.

```
name = ''
while name != 'your name':
    print('Please type your name.')
    name = input()
print('Thank you!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change the while statment to (name == "your name") then it will never goes under while scope. As you define value of name is empty string that's why the condition is false in first check. so it will print only "Thank You".
if you are satisfied with the answer please mark it helpfull. otherwise post your query in comment.

Answer (score -1):

When we changed the while loop as (While name == "your name"), the comparison returns false in the while loop. Once while loop receives False it will end the loop and goes below that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA750.png)

Comment: Please post the code in the answer, as code; pictures of code are less than useless since they're non searchable and add frustration to users with limited sight.

Comment: sure , next time I will do it